# Show all inputs in Laravel blade from @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, controller, laravel-blade

I have to join some tables to get specified columns, and make a new custom table on the homepage.

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $satwork = DB::table('drivers')
                ->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'drivers.vehicleId')
                ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'vehicles.deviceId')
                ->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'devices.companyId')
                ->select('companies.company_name', 'devices.device_type', 'vehicles.license_plate', 'drivers.driver_name')
                ->paginate(3);
    return view('/welcome', compact('satwork'));

}
```

I have a table in view blade, not every table column has the same number of entries, but I need them all to be visible.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Show us your view code

Comment: I wrote my code same as in answers. But I need all entries to be displayed

Comment: Do you wnat your table cells to be visible event if there is no content?

Comment: Yes, I want all cells to be visible

Answer (score 0):

view table column in blade file

```
@if ($satwork ->count() >0)
    @foreach($satwork as $data)
    //print your data into {{ }} like: {{ $data->company_name }}
    @endforeach
@else
  // no record found
@endif
```

after ending of table tag write this code. this is for pagination:

```
{!! $satwork ->render() !!}
```

Comment: I forgot to wrote that I have that part of code. But I need to show ALL entries, no mather if is not the same amount in all columns

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your view:

```
<tr>
    <td>Company name</td>
    <td>Device type</td>
    <td>License plate</td>
   <td>Driver name</td>
</tr>
@foreach ($satwork as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->company_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->device_type }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->license_plate }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->driver_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I wrote it like that... But it wont me show all entries, because some column has one, some have five entries. I need them all, no metter what

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat your table cells be visible event if there is no content, just put a space inside every cell, you can use the space character code `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

And this code is fully working.

```
$satwork = DB::table('companies')
                ->leftJoin('devices', 'companies.id', '=', 'devices.companyId')
                ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'devices.id', '=', 'vehicles.deviceId')
                ->leftJoin('drivers', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'drivers.vehicleId')
                ->select('companies.company_name', 'devices.device_type', 'vehicles.license_plate', 'drivers.driver_name')
                ->paginate(5);
    return view('/welcome', compact('satwork'));
```